# How to display all posts not in a post_format

Tags: wp-query, post-formats

Using WP_Query() I want to display all posts -except- those with the 'image' post_format. I tried this, but it did not work.

```
    $args = array(
      'relation' => 'NOT',      
      'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array('post-format-' . $post_format),
      )
    ),
        'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
    );
    query_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work because your tax query is missing the operator which should be set to `NOT IN`. So just add it like so:

```php
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'post-format-' . $post_format ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
    )
),
```

And please, **avoid using [`query_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/)** — use `new WP_Query()` or `get_posts()` instead — or hooks such as `pre_get_posts` for modifying the query parameters.